# How Do I Total a Filtered Column on a Razor Index Page Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, subtotal

I am trying to create a report that a user can filter using my `Index.cshtml`. The report is working correctly and I have one total in the footer that works just fine.

My issue is that the second total I need isn't based off of a specific field. It is based on an 'if' filter. Every variation I try returns a variety of errors. This is all still pretty new to me and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Hoping someone can point it out to me.

Here is my code for the pertinent part of the table:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var obj in Model.Results)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="5%" align="left">@obj.CRTCourt</td>
            <td width="5%" align="left">@obj.PILastName, @obj.PIFirstName @obj.PIMiddleInitial</td>
            <td width="10%">@obj.ArrestDate</td>
            <td width="10%">@obj.DISPConvictionDate</td>
            <td width="15%" align="left">@obj.ArrestOfficer</td>
            <td width="10%">@obj.DISPFineAmount</td>
            <td width="10%">@obj.DISPDueDate</td>
            <td width="5%" align="left">@obj.DISPFinePdInFull</td>
            <td width="5%" id="FilteredFine">
            @if (@obj.DISPFinePdInFull == "Yes") 
            {
                @obj.DISPFineAmount
            }
            else
            {
                <text>""</text>
            }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            Total Fines Assessed 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Results.Sum(i=>i.DISPFineAmount)
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            Total Pd
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- (This part is the area I am struggling with. 
                 Think I need to add something to my .cs to handle this, 
                 but not sure what?)
            @if (Model.Results.DISPFinePdInFull == "Yes")
            {
                @Model.Results.Sum(i => i.DISPFineAmount)
            }
            else
            {
                <text>""</text>
            }
            -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

And here is my `.cs`:

```
using DWITracker.Data;
using DWITracker.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data;

namespace DWITracker.Pages.Reports.CourtFines;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Incident> Results { get; set; }

    public string CourtSort { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Results = _db.Incident.ToList();
    }

    public void OnPost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string sortOrder)
    {
        Results = (from x in _db.Incident where (x.DISPConvictionDate >= startdate) && (x.DISPConvictionDate <= enddate) select x).ToList();

        CourtSort = sortOrder == "Court_Asc_Sort" ? "Court_Desc_Sort" : "Court_Asc_Sort";

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Court_Asc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.CRTCourt).ThenBy(s => s.PILastName);
                break;
            case "Court_Desc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(s => s.CRTCourt).ThenByDescending(s => s.PILastName);
                break;
            default:
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.CRTCourt).ThenBy(s => s.PILastName);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks very much for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Where` method to filter the items so that only those that have `DISPFinePdInFull` set to `true` are included in the total:

```
<td>
    @Model.Results.Where(x => x.DISPFinePdInFull).Sum(x => x.DISPFineAmount)
</td>
```

From OP: Got this to work with a slight edit:

@Model.Results.Where(x => x.DISPFinePdInFull **== "Yes"**).Sum(x => x.DISPFineAmount)

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks so much for the reply. I did try this, but I am getting 2 errors as a result. CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'. as well as CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type. Trying to follow documentation on these errors, but not really understanding it.

Comment: I see you worked it out. I recommend a bool for that type of data, or better yet, a nullable DateTime so you can store when it was paid in full. Someone is likely to ask that at some point.

Comment: Thank you. Very good advice. Replacing an old FoxPro program that had existing 'yes' 'no' date in that field. Could create another field with the date moving forward. That would work. Again thanks very much for the quick response and excellent answer and idea.